# Connecting to remote mysql database - aws server

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, heidisql

I have created a user in mysql database like this:

```
create user 'remote'@'localhost' identified by 'myUserPassword';
grant all on *.* to 'remote'@'localhost';
flush privileges;

create user 'remote'@'%' identified by 'myUserPassword';
grant all on *.* to 'remote'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

When I try to access it using heidi, I am getting this issue. I have done this before and I can access other servers easily using my newly created remote account. The server is on AWS. I am connecting it via SSH Tunnel.

[image]

I have checked the database as well

```
select * from user \G;
```

and I can see the permissions as well

```
*************************** 7. row ***************************
                  Host: %
                  User: remote
           Select_priv: Y
           Insert_priv: Y
           Update_priv: Y
           Delete_priv: Y
           Create_priv: Y
             Drop_priv: Y
           Reload_priv: Y
         Shutdown_priv: Y
          Process_priv: Y
             File_priv: Y
            Grant_priv: N
       References_priv: Y
            Index_priv: Y
            Alter_priv: Y
          Show_db_priv: Y
            Super_priv: Y
 Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
      Lock_tables_priv: Y
          Execute_priv: Y
       Repl_slave_priv: Y
      Repl_client_priv: Y
      Create_view_priv: Y
        Show_view_priv: Y
   Create_routine_priv: Y
    Alter_routine_priv: Y
      Create_user_priv: Y
            Event_priv: Y
          Trigger_priv: Y
Create_tablespace_priv: Y
              ssl_type:
            ssl_cipher:
           x509_issuer:
          x509_subject:
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: mysql_native_password
 authentication_string: i_have_removed_it_the_password
      password_expired: N
 password_last_changed: 2021-02-08 07:13:59
     password_lifetime: NULL
        account_locked: N
*************************** 8. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: remote
           Select_priv: Y
           Insert_priv: Y
           Update_priv: Y
           Delete_priv: Y
           Create_priv: Y
             Drop_priv: Y
           Reload_priv: Y
         Shutdown_priv: Y
          Process_priv: Y
             File_priv: Y
            Grant_priv: N
       References_priv: Y
            Index_priv: Y
            Alter_priv: Y
          Show_db_priv: Y
            Super_priv: Y
 Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
      Lock_tables_priv: Y
          Execute_priv: Y
       Repl_slave_priv: Y
      Repl_client_priv: Y
      Create_view_priv: Y
        Show_view_priv: Y
   Create_routine_priv: Y
    Alter_routine_priv: Y
      Create_user_priv: Y
            Event_priv: Y
          Trigger_priv: Y
Create_tablespace_priv: Y
              ssl_type:
            ssl_cipher:
           x509_issuer:
          x509_subject:
         max_questions: 0
           max_updates: 0
       max_connections: 0
  max_user_connections: 0
                plugin: mysql_native_password
 authentication_string:  i_have_removed_it_the_password
      password_expired: N
 password_last_changed: 2021-02-08 07:13:59
     password_lifetime: NULL
        account_locked: N
```

Comment: Looks good to me. And you are sure the SSH tunnel does not go to some other host with another MySQL server but without that user?

Comment: I can connect with the same user on via  consoled (sshed on that server)

Comment: In that case I'd say your HeidiSQL session settings have a difference to the console commands. You could post the ssh and mysql command lines (remove sensitive data!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is mysql and I was selecting the dll of mariadb. That's how I made it work.

[image]